# Mysql super strange syntax error?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, insert, insert-into

```
INSERT INTO pmessage (content, time, sent_by, to) VALUES ('k', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 84, 1);
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'to) VALUES('tt', '2011-04-28 14:04:45', 84, 1)' at line 1

The problem is i cannot see anything wrong with my syntax. There is nothing wrong with the column names etc, we tried many times. We copy/pasted the exact insert command from internet a few times than edited and still we got same error.

Anyone have any idea? The server is a MySQL 5 server

Comment: The competition on SO is fierce. 4 answers within a minute ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TO` is a reserved word. See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html.

Try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO pmessage (content, time, sent_by, `to`)
VALUES ('k', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 84, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

`to` is a MySQL keyword. You cannot just use it free like that. Try `[to]`

Comment: Yeah, backticks. The brackets are MS SQL, my mistake.

Comment: use backticks, not square brackets

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that `to` is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html), so you'll need to quote it.

Answer (score 1):

`to` is a reserver word: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 1):

Wrap "to" in backticks

```
INSERT INTO pmessage (content, time, sent_by, `to`) VALUES ('k', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 84, 1);
```